# Wordpress user_login field on new table field

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am using wordpress and I've created a new table in the wordpress database.

I have created a new table which contains a userid field

My question is, is there anyway to make a copy save/sync wordpress's user table user_login field into my new table so that every time there's a new user my table is also populated with the user_login field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to make a *one time copy* of the `user_login` field into your new table, you would do this:

```
insert into new_table (user_login)
select user_login from UsersTableNameHere
```

> Warning: adjust script accordingly with table and column names, since and do not know WordPress DB structure, neither your new table's structure. Also, make sure your `user_login` column has the same (or compatible) data type as `user_login` in the original users table

Now, if you want to replicate the `user_login` automatically whenever a new user is created, you should look into creating a trigger.

Read those on how to create a trigger:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html